# OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>' for a django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is my first submission here, so whenever I try to run `python manage.py runserver` for a Django project it didn't and it give an error I never saw before

---

Any ideas about what is this and how to fix it?
it gives me the following error:

### The Error i get

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GitHub\herafi\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\GitHub\herafi\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 618, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 603, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 318, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 324, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 364, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 380, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 278, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1204, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\vreoo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missing `__init__.py` file inside your project folder.  Please cross check to your project super folder & sub-folders, and makesure it empty `__init__.py` file is exists, if not you need to create it first.

Comment: `__init__.py`  are exist in both folders and they are empty, so i guess the problem is not from the project itself, I earlier did installed GDAL lib on my windows but it installed well, and then my python crashed and I reinstalled it again then this happened.

Comment: @NibrasShami have you done replace all `.pyc` files in your project too?

Comment: i have no idea what is that, i never did it in my past projects, sorry for being newbie so much but most of these are new for me